# First line in string written by VBA is a line break

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that is generating a string value to be written in a cell (a list of grant opportunities) from cell values (applicable grants).

The problem is that it's adding a line break at the beginning:
[image: See screenshot]

I need to remove this break line from the first line.

In the code below, the `"x"` logic and change to a different sheet is to check if the grant is applicable, and add it to the `grantc` variable if it is.

Code:

```vb
If Cells(fila, col) = "x" Or Cells(fila, col) = "X" Then
    Sheets("Grants").Select
    'col2 = col - 7
    col2 = col - 10

    If Cells(2, col2) <> "" Then
        If grantc = "" Then
            firstgrant = Cells(2, col2).Value
        Else
            firstgrant = grantc & vbNewLine & Cells(2, col2).Value
        End If
        lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, col2).End(xlUp).Row
        If lrow2 = 2 Then
            grantc = firstgrant
            grantc = LTrim(grantc)
            Sheets("Projects").Select
            If Cells(fila, lcol) = "" Then
                Cells(fila, lcol).Value = grantc
            Else
            End If
        Else
            grantr = Cells(2, col2).Value
            If InStr(LCase(grantc), LCase(grantr)) = 0 Then
                grantc = grantc & vbNewLine & grantr
                grantc = LTrim(grantc)
            End If
            fila2 = 3
            Do Until fila2 > lrow2
                grantr = Cells(fila2, col2).Value
                If InStr(LCase(grantc), LCase(grantr)) = 0 Then
                    grantc = grantc & vbNewLine & grantr
                    grantc = LTrim(grantc)
                End If
                fila2 = fila2 + 1
            Loop
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add a check at the end to remove the leading line break (CRLF) like this:

```vb
If Left(grantc, 2) = vbNewLine Then
    grantc = Right(grantc, Len(grantc) - 2)
End If
```

The reason why a line break is 2 characters is because under Windows, the line break is made of the Carriage Return (CR) character (ASCII code 13) and the Line Feed (LF) character (ASCII code 10). This will vary across OS (namely Mac).

So if you need this to run under both Windows and Mac, use :

```vb
If Left(grantc, Len(vbNewLine)) = vbNewLine Then
    grantc = Right(grantc, Len(grantc) - Len(vbNewLine))
End If
```